# The resource cannot be found using Area as separate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I want to use area as separate project.Whenever I try to navigate to this link :
                 http://localhost:100/module/home

I get the following error:
[image]

My solution contains two projects : entity_framework and module

My solution looks like:[image]

module is the project that I wanted to use as an area.My main project:
[image]

My Route.config in entity_framework looks :

```
public class RouteConfig
 {
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
     {
         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

         routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             namespaces:new string[] {"entity_framework.Controllers"}
         );
     }
 }
```

My moduleAreaRegistration.cs  :

```
   namespace entity_framework
   {
       public class moduleAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
       {
           public override string AreaName 
           {
               get 
               {
                   return "module";
               }
           }

           public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
           {
               context.MapRoute(
                   "module_default",
                   "module/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                   new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                   new string[] {"entity_framework.Controllers"}
               );
           }
       }
   }
```

I have added Index action in home controller in both projects and  Index view too but I am stuck in this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the area registration code being called? What do you have in it? Does the main project reference the area project?

Comment: @DavidG sir I have edited and shown my area registration also.Could you please see it once?

Comment: @DavidG Sir could you please help me figure out the problem? I am stuck in it.  This is the link that I went through and tried to create the modular project :**http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the namespace to

```
new string[] { "module.Controllers" }
```

in **moduleAreaRegistration.cs** .

Then I added this inside web.config inside main project:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

That worked fine for me.